# Error testeando componente vue con Jest

Tags: vue.js, axios, jest

Estoy haciendo tests con Jest a un componente vue que hace la llamada al endpoint que carga los trabajos, mediante una llamada get de axios. Y recibo este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leí lo que sugiere en el mensaje de error, pero no he llegado a solucionarlo.
Les comparto el codigo en caso de que me puedan iluminar. gracias de antemano

acá el codigo de mi componente

```
 <template>
  <main class="flex-auto p-8 bg-brand-gray-2">
    <ol>
      <job-listing
        v-for="job in jobs"
        :key="job.id"
        :job="job"
        data-test="job-listing"
      />
    </ol>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import JobListing from "@/components/JobResults/JobListing";

export default {
  name: "JobListings",
  components: {
    JobListing,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      jobs: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    const response = await axios.get(" http://localhost:3000/jobs");
    this.jobs = response.data;
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

codigo del test

```
import { shallowMount, flushPromises } from "@vue/test-utils";
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock("axios");

import JobListings from "@/components/JobResults/JobListings";

describe("JobListings", () => {
  it("fetches jobs", () => {
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: [] });
    //console.log(axios.get());
    shallowMount(JobListings);
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("http://localhost:3000/jobs");
  });
  it("creates a job listing for each received job", async () => {
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: Array(15).fill({}) });
    const wrapper = shallowMount(JobListings);
    await flushPromises();
    const jobListings = wrapper.findAll("[data-test='job-listing']");
    expect(jobListings).toHaveLength(15);
  });
});
```

Comment: Me parece que tu problema se refleja en [esta sección](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) de la documentación de **Jest**

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema hace tiempo y lo solucioné añadiendo el siguiente en la configuración de jest:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^axios$': require.resolve('axios'),
},
```